# why cant I install bower highcharts in yii2?

Tags: php, web, charts, yii2

I want to make charts in yii2. so I have to install bower highcharts. but when I try to install it, it cant be installed

[image]

what should I do to fix that problem?

Comment: Maybe google the error message?

Comment: it is evident that bower install command requires git installed and added to path variable.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very clear. You need to install Git in order to run `bower install`.

Hovewer, with Yii2 installing and using Bower is not required.

Yii2 is dependent on [Composer Asset Plugin](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin) - plugin that "allows you to manage project assets (css, js, etc.) in your composer.json without installing NPM or Bower".

You can't correctly and fully install Yii2 without installing this plugin first. Check [Installing Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-from-composer) official guide section:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

You can use this tool to install additional bower packages as well, for example by including them in `composer.json` along with PHP dependencies with special prefix:

```
"bower-asset/jquery.inputmask": "~3.2.2",
```

For more details check [plugin docs](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).

You need to install Git anyways. See [Downloads](https://git-scm.com/downloads) page on Git site. Installation depends on used OS.